# Would anybody be able to point me in the direction of legitimate Jewish meditation practices?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, avodah-zarah, practical-kabbalah

I have been looking for a meditative exercise which would complement my worship practices.

---

*either something to use before Worship to be put into the appropriate mindset or something which can be used outside of Shul as a personal development aid.*

---

The problem I have is I cannot get a straight answer from anybody regarding **what** that might be.

**I'm a Jew.** (*shocking, I know*)

I'm not a Buddhist or a Hindu or whatever else you might lump in with "meditation" faiths. I'm worried that I might be tricked into adopting a practice which is really a remixed form of a non-Jewish practice. It's important that the practice is rooted in Judaism.

I spoke with one person who directed me to a "*Rabbi*" who "*Studied Jewish meditation*" for many years. It turned out he traveled to India and lived on a **Ashram** (Hindu monastery) where he learned from Hindu teachers. I simply couldn't accept that guidance.

**I don't want to adopt a spiritual practice which would run counter to Judaism. I want something which is meditative but I know wouldn't be a form of idolatry being lumped into Jewish practice. That is my worry.**

I've heard that there are Chasidic practices of meditation but I've never been given a clear answer as to what that might be.

I've also heard about meditation ideas related to the Kabbalah but I don't know if that's legitimate or not. (legitimate meaning hearsay from Kabbalah interpretations VS Rabbinically endorsed practices) I'm basically left digging through a haystack of BS hoping to find my needle of truth.

Is there a specific practice which someone could point me in the direction of?

Comment: Hitbodedut? (Breslover...)

Comment: @Ezra 

Isn't Hitbodedut just praying privately in solitude? I'm not doubting it can be meditative but it isn't necessarily a meditative practice in the form of an organized meditation, you know what I mean?

Say controlled breathing or a mantra or some sort of physical movement for concentration/calmness/etc. 

You get what I mean?

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend R' Aryeh Kaplan's book, [*Jewish Meditation: A Practical Guide*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805210377). It is halachically kosher and quite comprehensive

If you are interested in more theoretical sources, same author has

- [*Meditation and the Bible*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0877286175)
- [*Meditation and Kabbalah*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0877286167)

---

**UPDATE**

Over the last couple of years, I've learned tremendously powerful Torah --both theoretical and practical, -- from Rav Doniel Katz at the [Elevation Project](https://elevationproject.com/). These teachings most certainly have potential to completely transform your *davening*, and more generally, your emotional connection to Hashem.

Comment: The last  link seems to have a loose relationship with Judaism.

Comment: Regarding Doniel Katz/Elevation Project: 

http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2022/03/how-to-meet-god_15.html

Comment: @Deuteronomy FWIW I strongly disagree with the analysis in the article you posted, - plenty of people in the comments do as well...

Comment: @gt698b And I definitely disagree with posting a link to a man that is "encouraging behavior which is likely illegal and definitely dangerous." All the best brother.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I love the term "likely illegal" :) slanders anyone you like and leaves you completely blameless (after all, he did not say it is "illegal", just did not turn out to be likely enough). "Definitely dangerous" - not according to doctors I spoke with, if done in a smart way guided by people who know what they are doing (which is exactly what the Rav says in shiur -- not encouraging blind use of this without guidance by any means).

Comment: @gt6989b "likely illegal" because it depends on the jurisdiction the reader is in. In most countries, it's **definitely** illegal. As for the "dangerous" part, the lecture way under-emphasizes that this is not and should not be for everyone and accordingly, is quite a dangerous message as profound and long lasting psychological trauma can result. Not really interested in debating, you posted what you felt was in others interest, and I commented in kind. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mussar movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musar_movement#Meditation), especially in its earlier forms, focused heavily on what could be called meditation. They would often spend substantial periods of time in the repetition of a sentence selected from the Bible or an ethical work.

A core part of their practice is "cheshbon hanefesh", which means taking time to conduct a self-assessment of strengths and weaknesses and where one can improve.

Comment: +1 The second part has little to do with meditation in the traditional interpretation of *cheshbon hanefesh*, but I very much agree with the first part. Could you post some source(s) describing the exact technique they used to meditate?